# How to Do a Merge for XML files in Code Smith?

Tags: xml, codesmith

I am using CodeSmith to Generate The Files in my Project. It has functionalities to Merge the C#/VB & SQL files using Insert Region & Preserve Region Strategies.

How Can I extend these to merge the XML files I am creating?.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Actually, CodeSmith supports merging XML files just like it does C# and VB files using regions.  You just need to use <!-- region Some Region Name --> and <!-- endregion --> to mark and name your regions of code.

Does that help or do you need more information?

Answer (score 0):

For T-SQL your code would need to look like this:

RegionNameRegex should be set to ^[ \t]*[ \s]*"?(?i:Custom)"?;
Language should be set to "T-SQL";

Your regions should look like this:

--region Custom Parameters

--endregion

I have created a sample template located [here](https://github.com/codesmithtools/Templates/tree/master/Templates/Examples/Merge/SQL).

Thanks
-Blake Niemyjski

EDIT: Updated link to point to the github repo since the community site is long gone.